# Use ACF select field to add a class to div inside a flexible content layout

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have built a simple page builder using ACF Pro flexible content fields. I want the user to be able to choose a background colour for the section using a radio button selector. I have set up the ACF fields but I want to get the value selected in the template and echo out a class name in the div which would then be styled with CSS.

I can't get the class name to show though, this is what I have so far:

```
if( get_field('background', $post->ID) == 'white' ):  
    $background = 'white';
elseif ( get_field('background', $post->ID) == 'light_grey' ): 
    $background = 'light-grey';
elseif( get_field('background', $post->ID) == 'dark_grey' ):
    $background = 'dark-grey';
else:
    $background = '';
endif;
```

At the moment nothing prints out at all. This code is in a file called by my the main template that has the code for the different layouts.

Ok revised code:

```
if( get_row_layout() == 'full_width_col' ):

        $bg = get_sub_field('row_background');

                        if( $bg ) {
                                $background = $bg['value'];
                        } else {
                                $background ='';
                                    }  ?>

<div id="row-wrap-<?php echo $row;?>" class="<?php echo $background; ?> row-wrapper full-width clear">
            <div id="row-<?php echo $row;?>" class="row">
                 <?php get_template_part('template-parts/acf/layout', 'full-width-col'); ?>
             </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `the_field('background', $post->ID)` to verify what it's returning? ACF can return label or value so that will help you double-check what you're getting. Maybe you're getting `White` back as a label. Also - you could simplify by making the ACF values equal your CSS class, so for example update `light_grey` to `light-grey` and then you can always just use `the_field()` instead of a conditional.

Comment: It is returning dark_grey which is the value. I will try your suggestion of simplifying it. How would that work with a radio button field?

Comment: yes, i changed the values in my example.

Comment: what i gave is for a radio button

Comment: Ah, I bet you don't have "format value" set to both.  See my update below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should show your whole code.  What you've posted above won't output at all.  Additionally there is no need to assign a variable as you have a value already...

your field values are set in ACF this way for a radio button:

```
white : White
light-grey : Light Grey
dark-grey : Dark Grey
```

(notice the space around the colon)

Now for your code:

```
$bg = get_field('background', $post->ID);
if( $bg ) {
    $background = $bg['value'];
} else {
    $background ='';
}

echo '<div class="mybackground '.$background.'">hi there</div>';
```

then your css:

```
.white {
 background-color:white;
}
.dark-grey {
 background-color:grey;
}
.light-grey {
 background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

You will need to customize a bit for what you're actually doing but this should work.

If you have format value set to just return value then change this line:

```
$background = $bg['value'];
```

to this:

```
$background = $bg;
```

Comment: made a few typos.  corrected now!

Comment: Thank you, I thought something must be wrong with they way I was doing it. I have my values set up as you have above, but my output code is wrong. I will have a go with the code above

Comment: also, if you're in a loop, you can omit the ",$post->ID"

Comment: I was trying to output a string based on the selection, rather than just outputting the value itself.

Comment: Why do you need to output a string that's different from the value? There are cases where that's helpful but if it's just adding a CSS class it simplifies code to just output the value directly.

Comment: you can output a string based on values, but why?

Comment: I am now getting an error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'value'.  I realised that I should have been using get_sub_field as it is in a flexible content field, so that was why I wasn't getting anything back before.

Comment: Yes I see that now, I was over complicating things! Thank you.

Comment: This is my code now, I get an error on the $background = $bg['value']; line 'while ( have_rows('flex_content') ) : the_row(); 
                    
                    
                    
      if( get_row_layout() == 'full_width_col' ):
                        
                        $bg = get_sub_field('row_background');
        if( $bg ) {
         $background = $bg['value'];
        } else {
         $background ='';
        }'

Comment: revise your code as an addon to your question and I'll compare again